# How receive xml response from SOAP endpoint?

Tags: java, xml, soap, httpurlconnection

My problem is that I have one endpoint url which if I put to the browser I can see the website. When I use this endpoint in postman program with correct request (xml) I am receiving xml response. Which is what I want. But I am trying to receive the same response in my java application but what I am receiving is the website(html).
I am not sure what is wrong

```java
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Envelope.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaler = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaler.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            Date now = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyhhmmss");
            fileName = "EMCS_" + tNumber.trim() + "_" + formater.format(now) + "_" + obtDto.getTransactionIdHost()
                + ".in";

            jaxbMarshaler.marshal(envelope, new File("C:\\Temp\\" + fileName));
            url = new URL(urlString);

            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
            connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",
                "Basic " + Base64.encode("USER:PASSWORD".getBytes()));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");

            BufferedOutputStream dos = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            File file = new File("C:\\Temp\\" + fileName);
            BufferedInputStream fileOutput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            byte[] b = new byte[(int) file.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                b[i] = (byte) fileOutput.read();
                System.out.printf((char) b[i] + "");
            }

            dos.write(b);
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            fileOutput.close();

            System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + connection.getResponseCode());
            BufferedOutputStream responseWebsite = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream("C:\\Temp\\response.html"));

            InputStream in = url.openStream(); // IMPORTANT TO READ PROPERLY DATA
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder result2 = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                responseWebsite.write(line.getBytes());
                result2.append(line + "\n");
            }

            responseWebsite.close();
```

By using code above I am posting request and getting HTML response instead of XML. What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I edited post cause I need give more explanation I think. My problem is that in 
'reader' variable bytes which I am receiving are HTML not XML. I want XML.

**EDIT2**

So I can not give a link to repo cause is not me private project. But when I am using postman and sending request to endpoint with

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:de.aeb.xnsg.emcs.bf" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body><ns2:request>...
```

body which I genereate with my app I am receiving

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:response>...
```

And that is good.
And response in postman is pure XML which I want.

But when I put this endpoint to chrome for example I am receiving website where I can find other endpoints/wsdls to this service but in different language(French, German etc).

**EDIT 3**
SOLVED

My problem was that I have specified Accept-Encoding

```java
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
```

when I removed it I could read proper response from stream.

But also I was able to read this message by using GZIPInputStream, but not sure which solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem is in this line `new FileOutputStream("C:\\Temp\\response.html"));`?and you should change extension to response.xml

Comment: No. This is my own file which I am saving after I receive response.

Comment: It has only HTML tags or html somehow mixed with xml? Can you give an example?